# Install Ubuntu on Asus Eee-PC 1005PE - Dealing with special partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, gparted, eeepc

I have an Asus EeePC 1005PE netbook and I'm planning on doing a massive re-partitioning (going to install Ubuntu, Mint, XP, etc).

I've noticed it has 2 "special" partitions:

- a 10Gb Fat32 RESTORE hidden partition (used by BIOS "F9 recovery" feature)
- a 16Mb "unknown" partition at the end of the drive (used by BIOS "Boot Booster" feature)

So, for both partitions, my question is:

- Can I move/resize the recovery partition freely?
- What are the requirements for it? (I mean, for it still to be found by BIOS when I press F9/Activate BootBooster.) Partition table order? Partition type? Flags? Label? UUID?
- Can I make it a logical (instead of primary) partition?
- Must it be the flagged as boot?

Most importantly: Where can I find *any* official documentation about it? I've already seen much (mis)information about it. Some say Boot Booster partition must be last (in partition table), some say Recovery must be 2nd, that it must be bootable, etc. How can I know what is *really* needed for the BIOS to use both F9 and Boot Booster?

**Note**: I'm using GParted from a Live USB Stick (Mint 10 / Ubuntu 10.10), and I've noticed that, since the filesystem type of the Boot Booster is not recognized, it can't move or resize it. Can I delete it and re-create it somewhere else? Whenever I create a 0xEF partition GParted crashes and quits and I cannot open it again (must delete the partition using fdisk / cfdisk).

Comment: Any official information is TOP SECRET and it is necessary to sign a Non Disclosure Agreement with own blood only :( If the half of mankind would not be forced to discover the wheel each day again, again and again then ... hm, on the other side it seems it is OK :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an eeePC 1000HE and have partitioned it many times. First I must say that if you think to delete this 2 little partitions you will lose your boot booster and it will boot with  "ASUS" gray boot screen instead of quick black screen.(which is very important and will give you at least 10 sec. of advantage in booting time) I do not recommend you to move, to delete or to touch this parts.
I have triple boot (Ubuntu netbook 10.04, Meego and XP).You can make partitions with Gparted and with XP hard disk manager without touching those parts.

Comment: But can i move them around, at least resize them? Is the order in the partition table relevant?